# unsigned _stdcall.... implicitly an int?

Tags: c++, function, return

A function with this signature:

```
unsigned _stdcall somefunction (LPVOID lParam);
```

does it mean that it implicitly returns an integer?  As unsigned really isn't a value by itself?  And _stdcall is a calling convention....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`unsigned` is a shortcut for `unsigned int`, so this function returns an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned` is a type all by itself and it's the same as `unsigned int`. Why anyone would ever bother to write `unsigned int` (especially in type casts where the extra space impairs the human capacity to quickly visually parse an expression with lots of parentheses) is beyond me.